# Fixed_quad Error With Functions

Tags: python, python-2.7

Keeping it simple:

```
----------------------------------

from mpmath import *
from scipy.integrate import *
mp.dps=30
def F(x):
    return Q**(x)
Q=735
print fixed_quad(F,0,1,n=1)[0]
print fixed_quad(F,0,1,n=2)[0]
print fixed_quad(F,0,1,n=3)[0]
--------------------
returns
 27.1108834235
 93.1213589089
109.673420158
```

However, if I change F(x) from “Q**(x)” to even just a simple function—e.g., “cos(x)”—I get

```
--------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Test.py", line 7, in <module>
    print fixed_quad(F,0,1,n=1)[0]
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/scipy/integrate/quadrature.py", line 67, in fixed_quad
    return (b-a)/2.0*sum(w*func(y,*args),0), None
  File "Test.py", line 5, in F
    return cos(x)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/mpmath/ctx_mp_python.py", line 984, in f
    x = ctx.convert(x)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/mpmath/ctx_mp_python.py", line 662, in convert
    return ctx._convert_fallback(x, strings)
  File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/mpmath/ctx_mp.py", line 614, in _convert_fallback
    raise TypeError("cannot create mpf from " + repr(x))
TypeError: cannot create mpf from array([ 0.5])
```

Is this some known bug?  Or is “fixed_quad” only meant for certain uses, not general integration (like “trapz”)?

All of the other regulars (“quad”, “dblquad”, “tplquad”, “nquad”) donʼt seem to have that problem/error.

Comment: The [documentation](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.integrate.fixed_quad.html#scipy.integrate.fixed_quad) indicates that the function "must accept vector inputs". Perhaps `cos` can't accept vector inputs.

Comment: Well then, I guess that means I'll just have to make my own universal version!   P=)